# Problem import pandas with conda: No module named pandas

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, conda

im having proble with importing pandas in my script

I did this:

[image]

Conda list:

[image]

Then:

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

You have to run python for your script in your terminal. So just type

```sh
python newspaper_receipe.py
```

Answer (score 0):

## Windows

AFAIK, Windows resolves how to run file types to programs in the registry. So it is likely the command shown is pointing back to a system-level Python installation.

To get around whatever is in the registry, you can either

```
conda activate prueba
python newspaper_receipe.py
```

or

```
conda run -n prueba python newspaper_receipe.py
```

## Unix

#### Adjust Shebang

One possible problem is needing to adjust the shebang on the script. It needs to be something like:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

so that the system runs the script with the Python prioritized in the active shell session.

#### Override Shebang

One can also explicitly direct a script to run in that Python at the `conda run`:

```bash
conda run -n prueba python newspaper_reciepe.py
```

That is, this would override the shebang and use the **prueba** env's `python`.

Answer (score -1):

you have to install pandas before importing it, try to write in your terminal:

```
pip install pandas
```