# Executing .py file from Command Prompt raises "ImportError: no module named geopandas"- Script works in Spyder (using anaconda)

Tags: python, anaconda, command-prompt, geopandas

I have a python script that accomplishes a few small tasks:

1. Create new directory structure
2. Download a .zip file from a URL and unzip contents
3. Clean up the data
4. Export data as a .csv

The full .py file runs successfully giving desired output when in Spyder, but when trying to run the .py from Command Prompt, it raises "ImportError: no module named geopandas"

I am using Windows 10 Enterprise version 1909, conda v4.9.2, Anaconda command line client v 1.7.2, Spyder 4.2.3.

I am in a virtual environment with all the needed packages that my script imports.
The first part of my script only needs `os` and `requests` packages, and it runs fine as its own .py file from Command Prompt:

```
import os
import requests

#setup folders, download .zip file and unzip it

#working directory is directory the .py file is in
wd = os.path.dirname(__file__)
if not os.path.exists(wd):
    os.mkdir(wd)
#data source directory
src_path = os.path.join(wd, "src")
if not os.path.exists(src_path):
    os.mkdir(src_path)
#data output directory
output_path = os.path.join(wd,"output")
if not os.path.exists(output_path):
    os.mkdir(output_path)

#create new output directories and define as variables
out_parent = os.path.join(wd, "output")
if not os.path.exists(out_parent):
    os.mkdir(out_parent)

folders = ["imgs", "eruptions_processed"]
for folder in folders:
    new_dir = os.path.join(out_parent, folder)
    if not os.path.exists(new_dir):
        os.mkdir(new_dir)
    
output_imgs = os.path.join(out_parent, "imgs")
if not os.path.exists(output_imgs):
    os.mkdir(output_imgs)

output_eruptions = os.path.join(out_parent, "eruptions_processed")
if not os.path.exists(output_eruptions):
    os.mkdir(output_eruptions)


if not os.path.exists(os.path.join(src_path,"Historical_Significant_Volcanic_Eruption_Locations.zip")):
    
    url = 'https://opendata.arcgis.com/datasets/3ed5925b69db4374aec43a054b444214_6.zip?outSR=%7B%22latestWkid%22%3A3857%2C%22wkid%22%3A102100%7D'
    doc = requests.get(url)
    os.chdir(src_path) #change working directory to src folder
    with open('Historical_Significant_Volcanic_Eruption_Locations.zip', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(doc.content)
    file = os.path.join(src_path,"Historical_Significant_Volcanic_Eruption_Locations.zip") #full file path of downloaded
```

But once I re-introduce my full list of packages in the .py file:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import requests
import datetime
import shutil
```

and run again from Command Prompt, I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KWOODW01\py_command_line_tools\download_eruptions.py", line 17, in <module>
    import geopandas as gpd
ImportError: No module named geopandas
```

I am thinking the problem is something to do with not finding my installed packages in my anaconda virtual environment, but I don't have a firm grasp on how to troubleshoot that. I thought I had added the necessary Anaconda file paths to my Windows PATH variable before.

The path to my virtual environment packages are in
"C:\Users\KWOODW01\Anaconda3\envs\pygis\Lib\site-packages"

`echo %PATH%`  returns:

```
C:\Users\KWOODW01\Anaconda3\envs\pygis;C:\Users\KWOODW01\Anaconda3\envs\pygis\Library\mingw-w64\bin;C:\Users\KWOODW01\Anaconda3\envs\pygis\Library\usr\bin;C:\Users\KWOODW01\Anaconda3\envs\pygis\Library\bin;C:\Users\KWOODW01\Anaconda3\envs\pygis\Scripts;C:\Users\KWOODW01\Anaconda3\envs\pygis\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\McAfee\Solidcore\Tools\GatherInfo;C:\Program Files\McAfee\Solidcore\Tools\Scanalyzer;C:\Program Files\McAfee\Solidcore;C:\Program Files\McAfee\Solidcore\Tools\ScGetCerts;C:\Users\KWOODW01\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\KWOODW01\Anaconda3\Library\bin;C:\Users\KWOODW01\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Users\KWOODW01\Anaconda3\condabin;C:\Users\KWOODW01\Anaconda3;.
```

So it appears that the path to the directory where my `pygis` venv packages live are already added to my PATH variables, yet from Command Prompt the script still raises the "ImportError: no module named geopandas". Pretty stuck on this one. Hoping someone can provide some more troubleshooting tips. Thanks.

Comment: Does `pip list` (or `conda list`) list `geopandas` (in terminal, after having activated your virtual environment)?

Comment: Hi, yes `conda list` shows I have geopandas 0.8.1 installed in my virtual environment.

Comment: So, if you execute in terminal `conda activate pygis` followed by `conda list`, it will list geopandas 0.8.1. And after that, if you continue with `python3` and then in Python execute `import geopandas`?

Comment: Yes, I've done all that. After checking that `geopandas` is installed from the `conda list` output, I navigate to where my python file is located: `cd py_command_line_tools`. Then i execute `download_eruptions.py`

Comment: Sorry can you clarify? do you mean I should `import geopandas` in the command prompt after I `conda activate pygis`? I'm not sure we are on the same page.

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66131178/570918

Answer (score 1):

I figured out I wasn't calling python in command prompt before executing the python file.
The proper command is `python modulename.py` instead of `modulename.py` if you want to execute a .py file from the command prompt. Yikes. Let this be a lesson for other python novices.

Comment: Great! The difference is that if you use `python3 modulename.py` in your virtual environment, it will neatly run your Python installation in that environment, while if you run just `modulename.py`, your operation system will search for an application that should be used to launch `.py` files, which is your general installation of Python, not that one in the virtual environment.